# Как настроить Laravel Mix для сборки асинхронных компонентов Vue.js?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack

Использую [асинхронную загрузку компонентов](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html). Все работает, но не совсем так, как хотелось бы. Laravel Mix собирает `.js` файлы компонентов не в `public > js`, а просто в `public`. Во-вторых, было бы хорошо называть файлы названием компонента. Хотя второе не столь важно, главное разобраться с первой проблемой.

**app.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import router from "./router";
import App from './components/App.vue'

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
})
```

**router.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: "/",
            component: () => import("./components/ProductList.vue")
        },
        {
            path: "/cart",
            component: () => import("./components/ShoppingList.vue")
        }
    ]
});
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался.

```
() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "js/cart" */ "./components/ShoppingList.vue")
```